# un-nessesary permission check?

Tags: android, permissions

ello, i am trying to code the following function:

```
private int GetTwoLocationsAndDistance(Location location1, Location location2) {
        if (location1 == null) {
            location1 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            location 2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        }
        else {
            location1 = location2;
            location2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        return int Distance;
    }
```

(both location1 and location2 are initalized as null)

here, an error message comes up saying that a permission might need to happen.
but i already asked for permission onCreate(); with

```
eif (pm.checkPermission(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        alertboxGPS();
    }
```

(alertboxGPS is a box that pops up when permission is denied)
how do i fix this error?

Comment: "an error message comes up saying that a permission might need to happen" -- is this an error that is occurring at runtime? If yes, post the Java stack trace. Otherwise, is this a warning that is occurring in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The user can deny you the permission, that's why android studio suggests that you need to check if it's granted.

You can ensure that your app has the permission by adding this line in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Or continue with the request/check permission method, however, let the user retry if the permission is not granted but is crucial.